# How to tell a conditional generative model is overfitting or not? And how to split training and validation set?

Tags: neural-networks

I'm now working on conditional generative models, but it confused me in the training process.

My process:

1. split training and validation set, and a held-out test set
2. train the model and evaluate the validation set using the same loss as the training set

Here I have two main questions:

1. Is it rational to use the same loss for the training and validation set? Because the final aim of generative models is to generate some new data (like sentences) and evaluate them with some metrics (like BLEU), these "generative metrics" may not tell whether this model is overfitting or not.
2. How to split the training and validation set? For my dataset, I have certain conditions and sentences corresponding to every condition. How should I split them?

> - 95% conditions for training and 5% for validation?
> - 95% data in every condition and the rest 5% for validation?